# Template on member function in lambda deduced using auto

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, stl

In the code below, `events` is an stl container built from template policies where the underlying type is composed from types in inbound and outbound.

```
auto events = process::run<inbound, outbound>(args);
```

After processing events, I need to do some calculations based on runtime parameters.  Here's an example:

```
cool::transform(events.deltas(), [](const auto &current) { return current.method(); });
```

There are several methods we may want to use, ie we may call another method which may or may not return the same underlying type.

```
cool::transform(events.deltas(), [](const auto &current) { return current.other(); });
```

Is there a way to template this so I can declare:

```
cooler::transform<method>(events.deltas())
```

Bonus question: Can we use templates to only enable the code if the method actually exists on the underlying type?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to template this so I can declare:

Not really - there is no gotcha-free way of passing "a method" as a template parameter. You will have issues with overloaded/template member functions. The lambda solution you currently have is the best one - I suggest shortening `current` to `c` and using `auto&&` in order to reduce the boilerplate:

```
cool::transform(events.deltas(), [](auto&& c){ return c.method(); });
```

---

> Can we use templates to only enable the code if the method actually exists on the underlying type?

Yes, you can use the [**detection idiom**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) to check whether or not an expression is valid. I wrote an article that covers it and other more powerful/terser techniques: ["checking expression validity in-place with C++17"](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/checking_expression_validity_in_place.html).

Comment: Thanks, I still forget auto&& till I see it.  On the first question, what's the gotcha on declaring the lambda as some callable and using that information? What if I moved method() out of the underlying type class definition and instead declared it as an inline method?